# What is the word for the document containing the questions of an examination?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the document containing the questions, exercises or problems that students taking an exam are supposed to answer ?

I thought about "question sheet" by parallelism to "answer sheet", but I am looking for a word or expression that does not contain "question" because I am going to use this word later in the same sentence.

In French we say "énoncé" (lit. "utterance") or "sujet". I found about "subject" in relation to exams, but it seems to mean the topic/notions/field of knowledge the exam is about rather than the precise document and set of questions asked for a definite exam session.

I need to tell a student to better read the [énoncé] because they seem to have not seen or payed attention to a very easy question.

Comment: The *exam* or *test* is the document with the questions, as in *"There was a major scandal when one of the students somehow managed to download a copy of the **exam** the day before it was to have been given."*

Comment: You can use a word twice in the same sentence. If it is a noun you can use a pronoun on the second use, as long as the referent is clear.  *You should read the question again, as **it** is a very easy one which you should not have gotten wrong.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word for a question sheet is a **paper** as in the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/paper)

> 3 *British* A set of examination questions to be answered at one
>   session.

Example use:

> we had to sit a three-hour paper

Comment: Also known as **exam paper** or **examination paper**.

Answer (score 3):

This can slightly vary depending on the country. As Weather Vane has said, "paper" can be used, but I believe that is more of a UK thing. In Canada, we would typically just say "exam" to reference the sheet. For example, before an exam starts, a teacher would say something like

> I'm going to hand out the exam, do not look at it until I say so.

and then hand everyone an exam paper. Then, before you start writing, you would flip over *the exam*.

So, when talking about the physical sheet of questions, you can simply use "exam".